# Is a C# decimal cultural dependent

Tags: c#, .net, culture

I'm going through some code from another developer and I found some code that seems... well ugly and unnecessary.

I understand that when parsing strings, we need to use cultural info properly when otherwise you can get into the "1.2" vs "1,2" type issues.  In this case, the developer is using a NumericUpDown which is stored as a decimal.

```
float fValue = System.Convert.ToSingle(numericUpDown1.Value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

My questions are:
- is the following code equivalent? 
- Will cultural info be handled properly?
- Can this cast throw an exception?

```
float fValue = (float)numericUpDown1.Value;
```

If they are not equivalent (or safe) can you please explain why and propose a "correct" solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Convert.ToSingle(value, culture)` calls `((IConvertible)value).ToSingle(culture)`. `decimal`'s `IConvertible.ToSingle` then ignores the passed-in culture and returns `Convert.ToSingle(value)`, which  just returns `(float)value`.

Yes, your code is equivalent.

Comment: _"then ignores the passed-in culture"_ It doesn't ignore it. Instead the overload `Convert.ToDouble(Object, IFormatProvider)` is executed.

Comment: @user2190035 Er... what? No. No, `Convert.ToDouble` doesn't get involved in a conversion to `float`/`Single`. And check [the reference source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/decimal.cs) if you don't believe that `float IConvertible.ToSingle(IFormatProvider provider)` ignores `provider` like I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code is equivalent to that only if the numericupdown1 value is small.
but if that value is 41.00027357629127 or something like this it will return  4.10002732E+15.

so,by using  float.Parse("numericUpDown1.Value", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat); you can get the exact value